# aspnet core deployment on production machine is looking for appsettings.json using development machine path

Tags: .net-core, deployment, publish

Following the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-3.1) I used VS 2019 to publish an Asp Net Core app.
Following the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle) to deploy an app on IIS.
I have the correct ASP.NET Core Module and Runtime (3.1) installed for my project.
When navigating to the app's home (any) page, I get "This site can't be reached" response page. This is not an error page from IIS on my VPS, it seems to be a default page / message from the browser.
There are no error messages from IIS events on my VPS.

To my understanding, Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) isn't starting the application, though the application pool shows 1 app assigned to it.

So using the web.config, I set logging to true.

`<aspNetCore processPath=".\IS4.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">`

I then went into the project's physical directory on the VPS, right-clicked on IS4.exe and ran as administrator. That resulted in an error that got logged.

[Here's a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78LPk.jpg)

So my app's program.cs is being passed an empty string instead of a URI. But it is using the path from my development laptop; NOT the path from set in the web.config's environment variables on the production machine.

**THERE ARE NO HARDCODED URLs / URIs at all in the project**. All variables requiring a URL / URI are set in the appsettings.json and in environment variables. EG: Configuration["AppURLS:IS4BaseUrl"]

So why doesn't line 12 and line 15 of the log file say:

blah blah blah ....................in C:\inetpub\IS4\Program.cs:line 81

and

at IS4.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\inetpub\IS4\Program.cs:line 58

I haven't found a good google search term or phrase that leads me to an answer, so I thought to ask here.
Why is the program.cs logging out my development environment's project directory and not the directory of the server that I am trying to deploy it on. I think that is the root of my deployment problems, or at least a starting point.

Anybody have any ideas? Thx

Answer (score 0):

So I am still not sure why the error log pointed to my laptop directory rather than the deployment server's directory, but I noticed that my db connection string wasn't properly escaped. Once I fixed the connection string the app started and I was able to navigate to the app and browse the site.

Spelling and escaping strings are my bane :(